# Visual Studio Team Services - Assigned Test Cases on Sprint Board

Tags: azure-devops

We are struggling to find answers to our questions related to the workflow of test plan and test case execution.

The root problem is that when a team member is looking at the sprint board, they do not see any information or tasks of the test cases that they are assigned to execute. Simply, how is a team member supposed to know that they have to execute a test case for the current sprint?

We don't understand why when we assign a test case to a team member that a task or something isn't created automatically such that the team member is able to "see" the assigned work on the sprint board.

Are we supposed to manually create a task for the team member and then link the newly created task to the test case? If so, how do we create this link?

The frustration is that we have one place where we are assigning team members test cases to execute, but there is no way to view what test cases are assigned in our sprint board. The sprint board is used to track work to be done for the sprint. Why is there no way to view assigned test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that a Test Case isn't in the Task category under the covers which means it does not show up on the board.  If you had a lot of tests, it could get kind of messy.  You might also have regression test cases which are not linked to a PBI (Product Backlog Item) in the Sprint but still need to be executed.  This is why we have a test plan instead of having it all on the board.

I generally do it this way

- Create a Test Plan for the Sprint.
- Add a Requirements-based suite scoped to the Iteration Path for that sprint, this will add all the PBIs for the sprint.
- Now, any test cases you create under the PBIs will be linked to that Work Item and any pre-linked test cases will be displayed in the test suite.
- You can add a static suite now with any other test cases (eg regression) which you want to run for the sprint
- In your Task board, create a task(s) under each PBI to execute the tests for that PBI
- The DoD (Definition of Done) for the PBI is not complete until all the linked tests are passing.

Another option might be to use the new feature to see linked test cases on the kanban board.

[image: Tests on Kanban Board]

A little tip is to Add the iteration path field to your card and then on the board filter you can just type "Sprint 2" and only the cards in that Sprint will be displayed.

Comment: I did exactly this, but in the details of the task, i provided the url to the tasksuite. makes it easier to navigate from the task to collection of tests it represents.

Answer (score 2):

Show the tests under Sprint Board is not supported. You can submit a feature request for this on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

To link a task to test case:

1. Open the task and click "Links" icon to open link panel.
2. Click "Link To..." button.
3. Set "Link Type" to "Test Case" and enter the test case ID in the dialog.
4. Click "OK" button.

[image]