# Make linked test cases visible in current sprint board in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

On the backlog board in a scrum project in TFS 2017, I can see the number of test cases linked to a backlog item. I can also see the status of the tests in some instances. I would like to see something similar in my current sprint. How can I get visibility to test cases linked to a product backlog item in the current sprint without clicking into a backlog item?

Answer (score 0):

Show the tests/test cases under Sprint Board is not supported. There is a [**user voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/16071952--add-test-from-scrum-board-sprint-board-on-user) submitted to request for this feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve it in future.

As a workaround for now, you can create a task and link it to test case.

You can reference this similar thread: [Visual Studio Team Services - Assigned Test Cases on Sprint Board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37035198/visual-studio-team-services-assigned-test-cases-on-sprint-board)